# Python screenshot 2+ monitors (windows)

Tags: python, windows, screenshot

How to make a screenshot with python, if connected to multiple monitors?

I tried:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId()).save('test.png', 'png')

import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grab()
im.save('test.png', 'PNG')
```

Both options provide a screenshot, only the primary monitor

If I use winapi:

```
hWnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, win_name)
dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hWnd)
i_colour = int(win32gui.GetPixel(dc,int(x),int(y)))
rgb = ((i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff))
```

I get a picture from a window in the second monitor. But it will be very slow.

If I press key 'printscreen' in the clipboard will be a normal screenshot, with all monitors. Is there a option to get a Full screenshot in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a mix of wxPython, win32api and ctypes:

```
import wx, win32api, win32gui, win32con, ctypes

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        dll = ctypes.WinDLL('gdi32.dll')
        for idx, (hMon, hDC, (left, top, right, bottom)) in enumerate(win32api.EnumDisplayMonitors(None, None)):
            hDeskDC = win32gui.CreateDC(win32api.GetMonitorInfo(hMon)['Device'], None, None)
            bitmap = wx.EmptyBitmap(right - left, bottom - top)
            hMemDC = wx.MemoryDC()
            hMemDC.SelectObject(bitmap)
            try:
                dll.BitBlt(hMemDC.GetHDC(), 0, 0, right - left, bottom - top, int(hDeskDC), 0, 0, win32con.SRCCOPY)
            finally:
                hMemDC.SelectObject(wx.NullBitmap)
            bitmap.SaveFile('screenshot_%02d.bmp' % idx, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
            win32gui.ReleaseDC(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow(), hDeskDC)
        return False

App(0)
```

Comment: How not to save the file, you can use this bitmap in PIL? Image.open()

Comment: Have you got a solution that's cross-platform?

Answer (score 9):

My [Desktopmagic](https://github.com/ludios/Desktopmagic) library provides this functionality for Python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3+.  It can return a PIL/Pillow Image or write a BMP.

Answer (score 1):

- install desktopmagic:

```
pip install Desktopmagic)
```

```
from __future__ import print_function
import desktopmagic
from desktopmagic.screengrab_win32 \
import(getDisplayRects,saveScreenToBmp,getScreenAsImage,getRectAsImage,getDisplaysAsImages)

""" getDisplayRects functions returns a list with all displays, in display order, like  [(0, 0, 1280, 1024), (-1280, 0, 0, 1024), (1280, -176, 3200, 1024)]  : (left, top, right, bottom)"""

screens=(getDisplayRects())
```

- take a screenshot of the second monitor

```
rect = getRectAsImage(screens[1])
```

- 0 for the first display 1 for the second and ...

```
#saves screenshot
rect.save('leftscr.png',format='png')
```