# take full screenshot python

Tags: python, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot for my screen(s).

I am aware of the function

```
pyautogui.screenshot()
```

The problem with this function is that it can take a screenshot for one screen only. I am  trying to take a full screenshot for all available screens (typically two). But, it does not seem to work in this regards.

Comment: On Windows you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941089/python-screenshot-2-monitors-windows

Comment: If not on windows please check https://pypi.org/project/Desktopmagic/

Comment: if you could reformulate your comment into an answer, I would accept it. Thanks @Pitto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you want to use a Windows system I would like to suggest you to use [Desktopmagic](https://pypi.org/project/Desktopmagic/), a Python Library.

Here's an example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from desktopmagic.screengrab_win32 import (
getDisplayRects, saveScreenToBmp, saveRectToBmp, getScreenAsImage,
getRectAsImage, getDisplaysAsImages)

# Save the entire virtual screen as a BMP (no PIL required)
saveScreenToBmp('screencapture_entire.bmp')

# Save an arbitrary rectangle of the virtual screen as a BMP (no PIL required)
saveRectToBmp('screencapture_256_256.bmp', rect=(0, 0, 256, 256))

# Save the entire virtual screen as a PNG
entireScreen = getScreenAsImage()
entireScreen.save('screencapture_entire.png', format='png')

# Get bounding rectangles for all displays, in display order
print("Display rects are:", getDisplayRects())
# -> something like [(0, 0, 1280, 1024), (-1280, 0, 0, 1024), (1280, -176, 3200, 1024)]

# Capture an arbitrary rectangle of the virtual screen: (left, top, right, bottom)
rect256 = getRectAsImage((0, 0, 256, 256))
rect256.save('screencapture_256_256.png', format='png')

# Unsynchronized capture, one display at a time.
# If you need all displays, use getDisplaysAsImages() instead.
for displayNumber, rect in enumerate(getDisplayRects(), 1):
imDisplay = getRectAsImage(rect)
imDisplay.save('screencapture_unsync_display_%d.png' % (displayNumber,), format='png')

# Synchronized capture, entire virtual screen at once, cropped to one Image per display.
for displayNumber, im in enumerate(getDisplaysAsImages(), 1):
im.save('screencapture_sync_display_%d.png' % (displayNumber,), format='png')
```

Comment: Did you try both?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another module if you mind: [MSS](https://pypi.org/project/mss/) (you do not need PIL or any other module, just Python; and it is cross-platform):

```py
from mss import mss

with mss() as sct:
    sct.shot(mon=-1, output="fullscreen.png")
```

The [documentation](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html) tries to explain more things, if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Using pyscreenshot library worked for me, I took a screenshot of all screens.

Source: https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/

```py
#-- include('examples/showgrabfullscreen.py') --#
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # grab fullscreen
    im = ImageGrab.grab()

    # save image file
    im.save('screenshot.png')

    # show image in a window
    im.show()
#-#
```

If you don't want to open the GUI, just comment the `im.show()` line.